# Mixpanel - unset people's property using Java API?

Tags: java, analytics, mixpanel

I am using Segment analytics's Java api for my Java based web-app to store analytics in Mixpanel. Everything is working fine but I now need to remove or "unset" a people's property from mixpanel through segment.
How can I do this through [Segment.com](http://segment.com/) 's java based library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you would have to use mixpanel as there is not method to unset properties in segment.

You will wait for segment to load by wrapping your function inside the analytics.ready function
 https://segment.com/docs/integrations/mixpanel/#settings

Here are the java methods that you need to user inside your function
    http://mixpanel.github.io/mixpanel-java/index.html?com/mixpanel/mixpanelapi/package-tree.html
    Unset
    http://mixpanel.github.io/mixpanel-java/com/mixpanel/mixpanelapi/MessageBuilder.html#unset(java.lang.String, java.util.Collection, org.json.JSONObject)

Hope this helps,

Cheers Analytics ML.